# Is there a way to listen events on users flows?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'd like to catch events in users flows. When an user is signin in, place a spinner or some similar loading icon while the user be waiting for some answer of B2C and then hide that, but i can't find any information about it. Do you know if this is posible, maybe with JS?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

there are a few ways you can do this but I suggest [Embedded Sign-In](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/embedded-login?pivots=b2c-custom-policy). In the samples provided, you can add a spinner that's triggered by functions like sign-in and sign-out. You can [use Javascript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-and-page-layout?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) on its own as well, along with [HTML templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy). For specific events as you mentioned I think the best route is the embedded sign-in so you can edit the JS sign-in functions directly. Please let me know if you have any questions!

Best,
James

Comment: I´ve just read it, but im actually using Angular MSAL for authentication. Do you know if is posible to do this along with this library?

Comment: Doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/embedded-login?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#configure-a-single-page-application), sample [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/apps/tree/master/apps/web-nodejs-msal-embeddedSignin). Library doesn’t matter. Just launch the auth lib sdk in the iframe.